# Rounding numbers in C++ error - expression must have integral or enum type

Tags: c++, enums

I have a function which is designed to round a number down to the nearest even number.

```
double round(double d)
{
  floor(d + 0.5);
  if(d % 2 == 1)
  {
      d = d-1;
  }
  return d;
}
```

However, this returns the error "expression must have integral or enum type" when I try to compile the code. The error is reported from the same line as the if statement.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can't use `%` on a double(in C++)

Comment: Also, the line `floor(d + 0.5);` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Adding to what @interjay said, it does do something - it returns a value, which you are silently throwing away. You need to assign the result to a variable.

Comment: What results do you want for inputs 1 (0, 2, or either?), 3 (2, 4, or either?), –1 (0, –2, either, or anything [will not be used]), and –3 (–2, –4, either, or anything?)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `floor()` function returns a double:

```
double floor (double x);
```

which is a floating point type, not an 'integral type', like `int` or `char`. Instead of calling `floor(d + 0.5);` which rounds `d` and discards the result, you'd want something like:

```
int i = static_cast<int>(floor(d + 0.5));
```

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? The question asks for code to round down to an even number. This neither rounds down nor rounds to an even number (when an odd number is nearer). Was the question written incorrectly?

Comment: The question asked, `However, this returns the error 'expression must have integral or enum type' when I try to compile the code. The error is reported from the same line as the if statement`. I was trying to explain why that particular error arose, and what could be done to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

The % operator is only defined for integers. You wanna use the [fmod() function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/fmod/).

[Bill is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16969206/961781) about a proper implementation of `round(double x)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
return floor(d/2 + 0.5) * 2;
```

Of course doubles are an approximation. For 10^50 you won't get even numbers probably.

Answer (score 0):

floor doesn't work in place, it returns the floor-ed value. Also % applies for integers so you can't re-use `d`. What you want is:

```
  int i = floor(d + 0.5);
  if(i % 2 == 1)
  {
      i = i-1;
  }
  return i;
```

Answer (score 0):

This version will do what you ask, returning an `int`.

If the parameter `d` is outside the range of an `int`, it returns `0` instead.
*(maybe you want to throw an `OutOfRange` exception or something)*

```
int roundDown2Even(double d)
{
    return (INT_MIN <= d && d <= INT_MAX)? ((int)d) & ~1 : 0;
}
```